# Stacking related lines together in notepad++

Tags: regex, notepad++

Hi so I'm trying to use find and replace in notepad++ with regular expression to do the following:
I have two set of lines
first set:

```
[c][eu][e]I37ANKCB[/e]  
[c][eu][e]OIL8ZEPW[/e]  
[c][eu][e]4OOEL75O[/e]  
[c][eu][e]PPNW5FN4[/e]  
[c][eu][e]E2BXCWUO[/e]  
[c][eu][e]SD9UQNT8[/e]  
[c][eu][e]E6BK6IGO[/e]
```

second set:

```
[u]7ubju2jvioks[u2]_261  
[u]89j408tah1lz[u2]_262  
[u]j673xnd49tq0[u2]_263  
[u]dv73osmh1wzu[u2]_264  
[u]twz3u4yiaeqr[u2]_265  
[u]cuhtg6r71kud[u2]_266  
[u]yts0ktvt9a3r[u2]_267
```

now I want to the second set to by places after each of the first set like this:

```
[c][eu][e]I37ANKCB[/e][u]7ubju2jvioks[u2]_261  
[c][eu][e]OIL8ZEPW[/e][u]89j408tah1lz[u2]_262  
[c][eu][e]4OOEL75O[/e][u]j673xnd49tq0[u2]_263  
[c][eu][e]PPNW5FN4[/e][u]dv73osmh1wzu[u2]_264  
[c][eu][e]E2BXCWUO[/e][u]twz3u4yiaeqr[u2]_265  
[c][eu][e]SD9UQNT8[/e][u]cuhtg6r71kud[u2]_266  
[c][eu][e]E6BK6IGO[/e][u]yts0ktvt9a3r[u2]_267
```

any suggestions?

Comment: Oh right, and all of the list is in order. so first line of first set goes with first of second set and so on

Comment: Hm, so you don't exactly need find and replace, you need a way to combine lines together intelligently.

Comment: Are both sets of lines in the same file?

Answer (score 1):

You can mark the second block in column mode using ALT and the left mouse button. Then just copy paste it at the end of the first row.

No need/Not possible using regex.

Comment: The problem is that there are too many of them to do that or I would haven't done that myself.

Answer (score 0):

I would solve this via a simple script written in Python or Ruby or something equally quick. This works, for example:

```
import os

path = os.path.dirname(__file__)

with open(os.path.join(path, 'file1')) as file1:
    with open(os.path.join(path, 'file2')) as file2:
        lines = zip(file1.readlines(), file2.readlines())

print ''.join([a.rstrip() + b for a, b in lines])
```

Running it gives the correct result:

```
> python join.py
[c][eu][e]I37ANKCB[/e][u]7ubju2jvioks[u2]_261  
[c][eu][e]OIL8ZEPW[/e][u]89j408tah1lz[u2]_262  
[c][eu][e]4OOEL75O[/e][u]j673xnd49tq0[u2]_263  
[c][eu][e]PPNW5FN4[/e][u]dv73osmh1wzu[u2]_264  
[c][eu][e]E2BXCWUO[/e][u]twz3u4yiaeqr[u2]_265  
[c][eu][e]SD9UQNT8[/e][u]cuhtg6r71kud[u2]_266  
[c][eu][e]E6BK6IGO[/e][u]yts0ktvt9a3r[u2]_267
```

Customize to suit your needs.

Comment: Thank you so much. can you tell me how to run this in notpad++. if not then I'll search for it myself.

Comment: @DemonHunter You can't run this in Notepad++, Notepad++ is a Text editor and not a scripting language.

Comment: So do I make this script to a .bat file?